# I want to all the values in the "EVENT_ID" to be displayed in the form of separate columns with respect to the "Email_ID"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Email Id's have duplicate value and corresponding to that there are unique event id's present. I want to transform it in the table such that for every email id all the event id's should be listed in different coloumns

Comment: Please provide some example data and some code where you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how it could be done in R:

we start from a dataset with 2 fields, email and event:

```
email <- c("john.doe@mysite.com", "jane.doe@mysite.com")

event <- c("event1", "event2", "event3", "event4")

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(email, event), stringsAsFactors = F)

df

  email               event
1 john.doe@mysite.com event1
2 jane.doe@mysite.com event2
3 john.doe@mysite.com event3
4 jane.doe@mysite.com event4
```

so far we have 2 different emails and 4 events.

using the dcast function you should be able to create the pivot table you need.

```
library(reshape2) # needed to use the dcast function
df.new <- dcast(df, email ~ event)

df.new
            email       event1  event2  event3  event4
1 jane.doe@mysite.com   <NA>    event2  <NA>    event4
2 john.doe@mysite.com   event1  <NA>    event3  <NA>
```

so the first record new contains:

```
df.new[1,]

  email                 event1 event2 event3 event4
1 jane.doe@mysite.com   <NA>   event2 <NA>   event4
```

and the second one contains:

```
df.new[2,]

  email               event1 event2 event3 event4
2 john.doe@mysite.com event1 <NA>   event3 <NA>
```

for more informations:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/pivot-tables-in-r/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks,It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using `tidyr` if you prefer:

```
email <- c("john.doe@mysite.com", "jane.doe@mysite.com")
event <- c("event1", "event2", "event3", "event4")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(email, event), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
  spread(event, event)
df
```

which returns

```
                email event1 event2 event3 event4
1 jane.doe@mysite.com   <NA> event2   <NA> event4
2 john.doe@mysite.com event1   <NA> event3   <NA>
```